# Why while compiling trigger the error appears?

Tags: plsql, database-trigger

I have a trigger

```
create or replace trigger company_trig
after insert or update on company
for each row
begin
     INSERT INTO company_table (
        DATA,
        OSUSER,
        TERMINAL,
        APP,
        SESSION_ID,
        CONTRACTFINID,
        SPREAD,
        MARGIN,
        MARGINCALIBRATE,
        CURRDEVALUATION,
        ADDITIONALFEE
        )

    VALUES(
        SYSDATE,
        SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'OS_USER'),
        SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'TERMINAL'),
        SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'MODULE'),
        SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SESSIONID'),
        :new.CONTRACTFINID,
        :new.SPREAD,
        :new.MARGIN,
        :new.MARGINCALIBRATE,
        :new.CURRDEVALUATION,
        :new.ADDITIONALFEE)
    ;   
end;
```

I also created table, which keeps values 'caught' by the trigger.

While compiling trigger I have an error saying that:

```
LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
2/1       PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol " " while expecting     ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma    raise return select update while with <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<    continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback    savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge 
Errors: check compiler log
```

The thing is when instead of

```
        :new.CONTRACTFINID,
        :new.SPREAD,
        :new.MARGIN,
        :new.MARGINCALIBRATE,
        :new.CURRDEVALUATION,
        :new.ADDITIONALFEE
```

I insert values, e.g. **1,1,1,1,1,1**
the trigger works perfectly (the test works perfectly),
but compiling trigger as above, I receive that error.
What might be wrong?

Comment: Looks good. Maybe the tool you are using to compile the trigger to somehow mangle it. Which tool are you using?

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer, v. 19.2.1.247

Answer (score 0):

The trigger is well done; the problem were spaces in front of each

```
DATA,
OSUER,
...
```

etc.
Replaced it with double TAB

Comment: PL/SQL does not require tab characters. Maybe there were some control characters in your code?